# iOS: Region Monitoring at a specific time

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, mkcoordinateregion

I want region monitoring at specific time. I have particular event time so I want to check is the user is in that region on that particular time

Answer (score 1):

you can send your app a silent push notification that will wake it up at the time you want. (you'd need a remote server to do this . there are also tons of services that offer to send push messages so you want have to write your own)

that's the only way appstore-safe way I know

```
- (void)receivedNotification:(id)pushMessage {
     //this will trigger the delegate to be called, check against the region there
     [self.locationManager startUpdateLocations];
}
```

Comment: What If user does not open push notification ?

Comment: a silent push doesn't need to be opened! - thats why you can't do it locally only :(

Comment: No problem I am doing already a push notification for it. Can you please tell me how to update location with silent notification ?

Comment: use the push as timer basically. make your server send you a push at a certain time

Comment: I get the push notification on device. Do I need to update location On Receiving that notification ?

Comment: More important question is HOW would I update device location upon receiving push Notification ?

Comment: or maybe startMonitoringRegion again!?

Answer (score 0):

just set the timer that goes off at specific time and start region monitoring. For example you can monitor the beacon regions,

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825"];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"skyBeacons"];
self.myregion =region;
self.myregion.notifyOnEntry= YES;
self.myregion.notifyOnExit =YES;
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myregion];
```

then you can use location manager delegate to catch the user/region.

Comment: the timer won't fire in the bg :)